# Force find_program to disregard CMAKE_SYSROOT

Tags: cmake

I am crosscompiling for STM32MP157 using cmake.

I have written a toolchain file. The relevant excerpts are as follows:

```
set(OSTL_TARGET_SYSROOT /opt/st/stm32mp1/3.1-openstlinux-5.4-dunfell-mp1-20-06-24/sysroots/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-ostl-linux-gnueabi)
set(OSTL_HOST_TOOLS /opt/st/stm32mp1/3.1-openstlinux-5.4-dunfell-mp1-20-06-24/sysroots/x86_64-ostl_sdk-linux)

set(STM32_TARGET_TRIPLET "arm-ostl-linux-gnueabi")
set(CMAKE_SYSROOT ${OSTL_TARGET_SYSROOT})
set(CMAKE_PROGRAM_PATH /usr/bin)
LIST(APPEND CMAKE_PROGRAM_PATH  ${OSTL_HOST_TOOLS}/usr/bin )

find_program(CMAKE_AR NAMES ${STM32_TARGET_TRIPLET}-ar PATHS ${CMAKE_PROGRAM_PATH} NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
```

This results in CMAKE_AR being loaded from the target sysroot and not ${OSTL_HOST_TOOLS}/usr/bin directory.

**How can i force find_program to look only in the paths given and not in any default directory?** I have already trie the option "NO_DEFAULT_PATH". But it doesn't work.

If I change the order of the program such that CMAKE_SYSROOT is set later, it works.

Comment: Before your `find_program` call you could set the variable [CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM.html) to `NEVER`, so CMake won't prepend your PATHS with the sysroot. Do not forget to restore given variable after your call, so user of your toolchain will have properly configured search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` argument to your `find_program` call.

```
find_program(
  CMAKE_AR 
  NAMES ${STM32_TARGET_TRIPLET}-ar 
  PATHS ${CMAKE_PROGRAM_PATH} 
  NO_DEFAULT_PATH
  NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
)
```

From the docs:

> The `CMAKE_SYSROOT` variable can also be used to specify exactly one directory to use as a prefix. Setting `CMAKE_SYSROOT` also has other effects. See the documentation for that variable for more.
>
> These variables are especially useful when cross-compiling to point to the root directory of the target environment and CMake will search there too. By default at first the directories listed in `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` are searched, then the `CMAKE_SYSROOT` directory is searched, and then the non-rooted directories will be searched. The default behavior can be adjusted by setting `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM`. This behavior can be manually overridden on a per-call basis using options:
>
> [...]
>
> `NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH`
>
> Do not use the CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH variable.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_program.html